# Asking user y/n when updating information

Tags: c#

I created a player class and made a array from that class for my menu driven player system I am trying to ask the user y/n if they want to update the goals and if they input y have them input the new amount and if no display a message and then ask them to update the assists and do the same for assists but when I put n into the program it keeps saying Exception was unhanded An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in SystemPlayer.exe . I I am not sure on how to fix this

any help would be appreciated

```
static void ProcessUpdate(Int32 number, String firstName, String lastName, 
                          Int32 goals, Int32 assists, Player[] players, 
                          ref Int32 playerCount, Int32 MAXPLAYERS)
{

    int playerindex;//index of the player number in Array
    char answer, answer2;

    if (playerCount == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: roster is empty");
    }
    else if (playerCount < MAXPLAYERS)
    {
        number = IOConsole.GetInt32("\nUpdate Player: please enter the player's number: ");
        //number = IOConsole.GetInt32(message);
        //Console.ReadLine();
        playerindex = GetPlayerIndex(number, firstName, lastName, goals, assists, players, ref playerCount);
        if (playerindex != -1)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: Player {0} currently has {1} goals and {2} assists \nEdit Goals?: Y/N: ", players[playerindex].Number,
                players[playerindex].Goals, players[playerindex].Assists);
            answer = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());




            if (answer.Equals('Y') || answer.Equals('y'))
            {
                goals = IOConsole.GetInt32("\nUpdate Player: please enter the player's new Goal total: ");
                if (goals < 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Goals cannot have a negative number");
                }
                else if (answer.Equals('N') || answer.Equals('n'))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Goals Not Updated");
                }
            }



            answer2 = IOConsole.GetChar("\nEdit Assists?: Y/N: ");


            if (answer2.Equals('Y') || answer2.Equals('y'))
            {

                assists = IOConsole.GetInt32("\nUpdate Player: please enter the player's new Assists total: ");

                if (assists < 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("assists Cannot have assists negative number");
                }
                if (answer2.Equals('N') || answer2.Equals('n'))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Assists Not Updated");
                }
            }


            //players[playerindex].LastName = lastName;
            //players[playerindex].FirstName = firstName;
            players[playerindex].Goals = goals;
            players[playerindex].Assists = assists;
            Console.WriteLine("\n{0,7}   {1,-20}{2, -20}{3,8}{4,8}{5,8}\n", "Number", "First Name", "Last Name", "Goals", " Assists", "Points");
            Console.WriteLine("{0,7}   {1,-20}{2, -20}{3,8}{4,8}{5,8}",
             players[playerindex].Number, players[playerindex].FirstName, players[playerindex].LastName,
             players[playerindex].Goals, players[playerindex].Assists, players[playerindex].Points());
            Console.WriteLine("Sucessfully Updated!");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }


        else
            Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: the player number does not exists");
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("\nUpdate Player: the player does not exist in the roster");
}
```

> Here is where my player class where the exception error happened

```
//Public Goals accessor
public Int32 Goals
{
    get
    {
        //Return member variable value
        return _goals;
    }
    set
    {
        //Validate value and throw exception if necessary
        if (value <= 0)
            throw new Exception("Goals must be a positive number");
        else
            //Otherwise set member variable value
            _goals = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is IOConsole and what is GetPlayerIndex, with the Equals, use the overloaded method call that use StringComparison Enumeration and use CurrentCultureIgnoreCase to remove duplication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

few problem with the code provided, if you say `No` to any of the question, the `if` that handle it is **INSIDE** the `Yes` statement

the setter of that property handle `<= 0` but your code is only checking for `< 0`

you should have a variable that will hold the new value and if it is valid assign it to the actual variable otherwise it will crash, if the user entered less than 1

do this, test again to see if it does fix the issue

bonus hint, go check this [String.Equals Method (String, StringComparison)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to remove the check for Y/y and N/n